# How can I concatenate 4 bytes to 8 in c++?

Tags: c++, bit

How can I concatenate 4 bytes to 8?

Example:

```
long var1 = 0x01011; //0001 0000 0001 0001
long var2 = 0x03034; //0011 0000 0011 0100
// MAGIC...
long result = 0x10113034; //0001 0000 0001 0001 0011 0000 0011 0100
```

Comment: Your example concatenates two 2-byte numbers into a 4-byte number.

Comment: `result = (var1 << 16) + var2;` Read bout shift operators in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Always use `unsigned` types for this kind of bit twiddling, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use shifts and sum to combine elements. In this case, you combine 2 4-byte ints into one 8-byte long long.

```
unsigned int a = 0x01020304;
unsigned int b = 0x0a0b0c0e;
unsigned long long c = (((unsigned long long)a) << 32)  + b;
// c=0x010203040a0b0c0e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using ul = unsigned long;

long concat(long var1, long var2) {
    ul result  = (static_cast<ul>(var1)<<16) | static_cast<ul>(var2); 
    return static_cast<long>(result);
}
```

This function returns the result you want, I didn't test it extensively but intuitively it should work as sample cases.

Comment: Is the cast to unsigned necessary since left shifts don't treat the sign bit in any special way?

Comment: Probably not really necessary so typecast could be merged after the OR operation but I didn't wanna take any chances as I don't have complete knowledge of how it's implemented in the CPU or specified in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

### The easiest way is probably:

**By using binary operators:**

```
unsigned long var1 = 0x1011; //0001 0000 0001 0001
unsigned long var2 = 0x3034; //0011 0000 0011 0100
unsigned long result = (var1 << 16) | var2; //Magic!: 0001 0000 0001 0001 0011 0000 0011 0100
```

By the way, I believe it's the fastest way of coding/computing it!

> Tip: Use unsigned numbers for binary operations because it could give surprising results otherwise!